# How to extract field value from PDF form in PHP

Tags: php, forms, class, pdf

We are developing PHP & MySQL based application. We distribute a registration form in PDF format. After filling form, user will upload PDF form to our application to register. We want to extract registration data in PDF form from PHP and save these data to database.

Can someone point me PHP classes for extracting field value from PDF form?

Comment: As far as I know this is impossible. You'd need OCR for this to work (so it is possible indeed ;) ): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

Comment: Thanks @hoppa. Registration form is not image in PDF. It is fillable PDF form. Pleae check this . http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro/create-fillable-pdf-forms.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713701/populating-pdf-form-fields-with-php OP uses php to fill form fields, maybe you can adapt its code to read them.

Comment: It is possible to have a fillable PDF send its data to a webserver if I remember correct. Wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: See here: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php

Comment: Thank you very much all for comments and suggestions. We chose the solutoin as @hoppa mentioned. It is easier for us. It would be great if there is 3rd party PHP classes to extract value from PDF form later.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative could be using an external program like http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/ and so something like:

```
$ pdftk file.pdf dump_data_fields
```

and then process the output. However, this would involve a lot of parsing logic and output processing.  Plus, if you cannot install binaries on your server, never mind. :)

It might be just simpler to do as [hoppa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295756/hoppa) mentioned.

**Edit:**  This question might be a duplicate of [The best pratice to parse PDF forms fields with PHP5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524284/the-best-pratice-to-parse-pdf-forms-fields-with-php5) that question has an interesting comment!